# Why is my data not being displayed when drawing the bar graph?

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I have an php file that is succesfully drawing the chart through the below script, but for some reason the chart is not loading the data, below is my script as well as the php file.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            showGraph();
        });


        function showGraph()
        {
            {
                $.post("sqlChart.php",
                function (data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                     var day = [];
                    var calories = [];

                    for (var i in data) {
                        day.push(data[i].day);
                        calories.push(data[i].calories);
                    }

                    var chartdata = {
                        labels: calories,
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: 'Calories',
                                backgroundColor: '#49e2ff',
                                borderColor: '#46d5f1',
                                hoverBackgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
                                hoverBorderColor: '#666666',
                                data: calories
                            }
                        ]
                    };

                    var graphTarget = $("#container");

                    var barGraph = new Chart(graphTarget, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: chartdata
                    });
                });
            }
        }
        </script>
```

php:

```
<?php 
$error = '';
if($error){
    print "<div class= 'h6 fw-normal text-danger'>$error</div>\n";
}  
require_once '../db.conf';
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname, $dbport);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    $error = 'Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ' ' . $mysqli->connect_error;
    require "Calories.php";
    exit;
}
            
$query = "SELECT day, calories FROM calorie";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $data[] = $row;
}
//free memory associated with result

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

I have tried changing both the script embedded in my html as well as changing the php but nothing seems to be working for me, I think it may be dues to not having the correct chart.js api?

Comment: What are you getting when u log the response in `console.log(data);` ? Please update your question with a screenshot of this log.

Comment: I hope your `chartdata.data`  should be like `data: day`